# How to change a url link to be displayed in rss?

Tags: browser, rss

Is there any specific command which we could add to any url so it shows any webpage in the rss mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. RSS is an independent format that has specific requirements. If a website doesn't implement a RSS feed you won't be able to just turn it into one.